# jQuery Accordion does not close

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

The accordion tab does not close if I click on the span inside the accordion navigation. What does I have missed?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        $('.accordion .second-title').removeClass('active');
        $('.accordion .radio-toolbar').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
}
 
    $('.second-title').click(function(e) {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
 
        if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        }else {
            close_accordion_section();
 
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
        }
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
.radio-toolbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #444; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 12px 7px -10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 12px 7px -10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 12px 7px -10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  display:none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.accordion {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
.second-title {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #444;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.strong  {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">

    
    
    
<a class="second-title" href="#getlogo">
<span class="strong">Logoanbringung</span>
</a>                      
         
<div class="radio-toolbar" id="getlogo">
</div>

    
    

<a class="second-title" href="#getmechanik">
<span class="strong">2-Ring Combimechanik</span>
</a>  
  
<div class="radio-toolbar" id="getmechanik">  
</div>


  
</div>
```

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
>   nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam

Comment: better use this plugin very easily http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this) instead of e.target

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        $('.accordion .second-title').removeClass('active');
        $('.accordion .swatch, .accordion .radio-toolbar').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
}

    $('.second-title').click(function() {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

        if($(this).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        }else {
            close_accordion_section();

            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works on the snippet but not on the final project. http://printnil.com/products/c2

Comment: The problem is that if you click (in your project) in "a.second-title" it works, but if you click in some of the span tags it doesn't work. So, why use <a> tag instead of <div> tag? If it is beacuse of the ponter, you can add the pointer with css with cursor: pointer -> http://jsfiddle.net/cjjn3rak/